# Grid layout with recycler view android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I found this code and adapted it to my project

```
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
    //totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();

    int[] firstVisibleItems = null;
    firstVisibleItems = mLayoutManager
            .findFirstVisibleItemPositions(firstVisibleItems);
    if (firstVisibleItems != null && firstVisibleItems.length > 0) {
        pastVisibleItems = firstVisibleItems[0];
    }

    if (!loading && visibleItemCount <= (pastVisibleItems + visibleThreshold)) {
        // End has been reached
        // Do something

        Log.d(TAG, "onLoadMoreListener ");

        getTagResults(mQuery, mMinId, mMaxId);

        // if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
        //      onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
        //  }


        loading = true;
    }

}
```

but this doesnt work it works for linear layout though. I have found lots of code for all the other layouts but i cant find how to load more results when end is reached.

Comment: you can check this tutorial http://wiki.workassis.com/android-using-multiple-layout-in-recyclerview/

Answer (score 8):

Use following code

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```